# Iterate through dictionary and store values

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdictionary

I have a dictionary of data which looks like this:

```
{
    asr = "4:23 pm";
    dhuhr = "12:02 pm";
    fajr = "1:17 am";
    isha = "10:47 pm";
    maghrib = "8:23 pm";
    shurooq = "3:41 am";
}
```

My goal is to determine which time comes next. My plan is to convert these to actual NSDates using this code:

```
//create an NSDate with todays date and the right prayer time
NSString *prayerDateString = [curDate stringByAppendingString: @" "];
prayerDateString = [prayerDateString stringByAppendingString: time];
NSLog(@"prayer date string: %@", prayerDateString);

//convert string back to date
NSDate *prayerDateAndTime = [dateAndTimeFormatter dateFromString:prayerDateString];

[dictionaryOfDatesAsDates addObject:prayerDateAndTime];
```

Which I think works, but I'm not sure if it correctly retains the format of the dictionary. Then to use `[currentDate timeIntervalSinceNow]` to check each one and assume that the smallest positive time interval will be the next time and to get the name, eg `asr`.

I'm not sure how to do the iteration and store the time interval value somewhere along with the name of the time in order to get which is the smallest value from this?

How would I go about achieving this?

Comment: use timestamps instead

Comment: The answers from yesterday didn't actually help then? If you use the filtering and sorting approach then you will have no iteration in your own code.

Comment: @Wain No, this is as far as I got. I thought I was heading in the right direction? The most voted answer yesterday said to iterate through using timeIntervalSinceNow...

Comment: You're heading in a direction. Both options from yesterday will work. Iterating means more code for you (but it is more transparent what's happening). I guess your dates are being created correctly in the above? And `dictionaryOfDatesAsDates` is presumably actually an array, not a dictionary?

Comment: @Wain Yeah, the output is correct and it's an array. I did think it would be easier to have a dictionary as I could more easily pull the name out earlier, but I guess an array works. I'll just keep trying I guess then. Been doing this for days...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you've got your dates and added them to an array:

```
NSArray *prayerDateAndTimes = ...
```

Following on from yesterday:

> Get a list of the dates, then use an NSPredicate to filter that list to dates >= [NSDate date], then sort it ascending. Then the first item in the filtered, sorted array will be the next date.

First, filter out dates that have already passed:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF >= %@", [NSDate date]];

NSArray *validPrayerDateAndTimes = [prayerDateAndTimes filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Now we can tell if there are any more dates today:

```
if (validPrayerDateAndTimes.count > 0) {
    // yay, sort to find the next one
    validPrayerDateAndTimes = [validPrayerDateAndTimes sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];

    NSLog(@"next date: %@", [validPrayerDateAndTimes objectAtIndex:0]);
} else {
    NSLog(@":-(");
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This works! So now I just need to find which name the given time corresponds to... Thanks!

Comment: nice and clean solution. But will not work if there are no more times for today. In that case the first time of the next date should be returned (if I understood well).

Comment: Yeah, that's right. It's always the first one of tomorrow if there are no more today, so I can implement that myself. Thanks again

Comment: The above technique will also work if you want to create a dictionary and store the date and the name into it so you have both. It just changes the predicate (replace `SELF` with the key name of the date) and instead of sorting with a selector, sort with a sort descriptor.

Comment: So whats the best way to get the next day's times? modify the predicate to tomorrows date? @Wain Thanks.

Comment: @RahimJan, not really clear what you're asking, but if you want to filter out todays dates then changing the predicate is the way to go.

Comment: I'm still stuck at how to get tomorrow's prayer times without the user opening the app. Right now once the prayer times for the day are done, the user has to reopen the app at midnight in order to get the new times.. which is a problem since I'm trying to set local notifications.. @Wain

Answer (score 0):

EDITED:

This should work. Change your dictionary to 24hour format (20:23). It will return the key that has the closest time to current time (even if it has no more prays for today, it will return the next day's).

```
-(NSDate*)initDateWithHour:(int)hour andMinutes:(int)minutes
{
    NSCalendar *calendar = [[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar] autorelease];

    NSDateComponents *components = [[[NSDateComponents alloc] init] autorelease];
    NSDateComponents *nowComp = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];

    [components setYear:[nowComp year]];
    [components setMonth:[nowComp month]];
    [components setDay:[nowComp day]];

    [components setHour:hour];
    [components setMinute:minutes];

    return [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
}

- (NSString*)getClosestTimeKey:(NSDictionary*)dict
{
    NSDate* now = [NSDate date];

    int secondsOfDay = 86400;

    int minDif = secondsOfDay;
    NSString* closestKey = @"";

    for (NSString* key in dict)
    {
        NSString* timeStr = [dict objectForKey:key];

        NSArray *array = [timeStr componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
        int hour = [[array objectAtIndex:0] intValue];
        int minutes = [[array objectAtIndex:1] intValue];

        NSDate *d = [self initDateWithHour:hour andMinutes:minutes];

        int dif = [d timeIntervalSince1970] - [now timeIntervalSince1970];
        if (dif < 0)
            dif += secondsOfDay;

        if (dif < minDif)
        {
            minDif = dif;
            closestKey = key;
        }
    }
    return closestKey;
}
```

And you use it by:

```
NSString* key = [self getClosestTimeKey:dict];
```